# Guide to migrate from delayed_job to resque?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, resque

Does anyone have or know of a guide for how to migrate from Delayed Job to Resque? I can't find any on Google and figure I must not be the first one doing this. Just a general list of changes that need to made and things to watch out for would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no guide that I could find, but the missing piece of the puzzle is Resque scheduler. Once you get all the Resque stuff running on your server, the actual Rails code changes are incredibly simple. So if you happen to be doing this look for Resque Scheduler and then have at it.

Answer (score 4):

I have just found this [guide](http://blog.railsupgrade.com/2011/08/replace-delayedjob-with-resque.html).